# Specific substring of string

Tags: c

Say I have these two arrays:

```
char string[] = "String";
char substring[0][3];
```

If I want the first three letters of string `str` into the multidimensional array `substring`, I can do this:

```
memcpy(&substring[0][0], string, 3);
```

But what can I do to get number 3 and 4 `in` from array string into array `substring`?

```
memcpy(&substring[0][0], string, *//CHAR 3 AND 4/* );
```

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: `char string[5] = "String";` is not long enough: try `char string[] = "String";`

Comment: Please post your *actual code*, the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Don't guess corrections to code faults in the question, this is not a dynamic code modifying site.

Comment: It is quite clear what i want to achieve, isnt it?

Comment: Nope: *number 5 and 6 ("in")* does not match the code posted. Please show your attempt as the MCVE requested.

Comment: Please delete this question, consider, and then ask a new question, to show a credible attempt as to your needs. This site does not "fill in the blanks" to code you can't write.

Comment: I already pointed out two faults. Please read the help pages and how to ask.

Comment: `char substring[0][3]` is not enough to store 3 characters

Comment: `char substring[0][3];` --> `char substring[1][3+1];`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear, but this is my code for getting characters 'i' and 'n' from a string array into a substring array.

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
  char string[]="String";
  char substring[2];
  char *pointer;

 pointer=string;

 substring[0]=*(pointer+3);
 substring[1]=*(pointer+4);

printf("%c %c",substring[0],substring[1]);

}
```